# "Minimal" source files to create Android app using Eclipse + ADT

Tags: android

I am trying to understand the anatomy of a MINIMAL Android application, using Eclipse + ADT (Android Development Toolkit).

Please can you advise what is the MINIMAL set of source files I need, for example :-

```
src / package / MainActivity.java
res / layout / activity_main.xml
res / menu / activity_main.xml  (??)
AndroidManifest.xml
(any other source files needed?)
```

Please can you advise what is the MINIMAL that I need to put into each file in order for it to run on the AVD (Android Virtual Device) ?

For example, which of these files needs to contain reference(s) to which other files, etc?

Comment: What is this MINIMAL application supposed to do?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, application to display "Hello World".  Thanks.

Comment: I think all you need to do is just create a new Android project with the wizard in Eclipse, and look at the files it creates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strictly speaking the minimal project that displays *Hello World* is

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── res
└── src
    └── com
        └── example
            └── minimal
                └── Minimal.java
```

### Minimal.java

```
package com.example.minimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Minimal extends Activity {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello World!");
        setContentView(tv);
    }

}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.minimal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="Minimal">
        <activity android:name="Minimal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks dtmilano, that's brilliant  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get away with just a single MyActivity.java and the manifest file, if you inflate the layout programatically. Later Eclipse Tools will create many more files (in ..drawables, layout, menu, values) by default. You can however delete them all if you make sure that the manifest doesn't refer to any icons or strings. I guess it's not seen as good practice, but it can be done.

Comment: @Those who edited my post. Don't changes my words. If you have something better to say, write your own answer

Answer (score 0):

**A minimal `build.xml`** which can build and install [dtmilano's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888991/895245):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyName" default="help">
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

then:

```
ant clean
ant debug
ant install
```

Tested on Android 23, Ubuntu 15.10. Just make sure that `adb install` works before running this.

[On a repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/tree/8fef86f1b4707b8834991ba151131d10a3a3ba64/min) to make getting the code easier.