# how to find aapt version

Tags: android, build, aapt

I am trying to build an android application from the command line (the one described at ["Minimal" source files to create Android app using Eclipse + ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888398/minimal-source-files-to-create-android-app-using-eclipse-adt) ) and aapt is failing with some errors. How do I discover what version of aapt I am running?
Is there only one version?
Here is the command line I am running:
aapt package -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res -J gen
The output does not show the version number, nor does there appear to be any flag to set to show the version.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this solution:

```
aapt v
```

Comment: Thanks , I just saw that. I was blinded by all of the - and -- flags