# where does aapt look for resource identifiers

Tags: android, build, aapt

I am trying to build an android application from the command line (the one described at "Minimal" source files to create Android app using Eclipse + ADT ) and aapt is failing with some errors.
The errors look like:

> AndroidManifest.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for
>   attribute 'versionCode' in package 'android'
> and are repeated once
>   for each attribute in AndroidManifest.xml.

The command I am running is:
`aapt package -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res -J gen`
So I think I am somhow failing to define for aapt where to look for resource identifiers. Is this correct?
How do I tell aapt where to look for resource identifiers?
I am running Android Asset Packaging Tool, v0.2.
Thanks, Jim.

edit:I should have included a link to the page with the source I copied:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888398/minimal-source-files-to-create-android-app-using-eclipse-adt

Comment: How does your AndroidManifest.xml look like?

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    `package="com.example.minimal"`
    `android:versionCode="1"`
    `android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" /><br>

    <application android:label="Minimal"><br>
        <activity android:name="Minimal"><br>
            <intent-filter><br>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/><br>
            </intent-filter><br>
        </activity><br>

    </application><br>

</manifest><br>
`

Comment: Tried to fix the formatting, I am a newb.

Comment: I found the answer. The resource identifiers come from the android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-vv/android.jar

Comment: The command I ended up with is --- aapt package -v -m -J $WORKINGDIR/gen -M $WORKINGDIR/AndroidManifest.xml -S $WORKINGDIR/res -I $PLATFORM/android.jar:

Answer (score 0):

The Best example I found on Internet so far to create android app is https://geosoft.no/development/android.html also in case if you are using support libraries app theme, it would be difficult to figure out how to create R.java classes, I would suggest you to use this reference answer[How to compile an Android app with aapt2 without using any build tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274657/how-to-compile-an-android-app-with-aapt2-without-using-any-build-tools/57153503#57153503) by which you will be able to use android.jar's general theme without any dependency on any support library.