# What does android's resource compiler (aapt) use to identify legal XML?

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt

aapt identifies illegal symbols in res files.  What is the authority on which it does this?

It is using XPAT to do the parsing but it runs XPAT in non-validating mode: there is no schema.

Based on a read of the code, I believe that it considers a symbol invalid -- element name or attribute name -- if it can find it in a table that it appears to load from the platform definition jar file (android.jar).  I lose the trail at that point.

This question is similar, but the answer is unrewarding:

[where does aapt look for resource identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281052/where-does-aapt-look-for-resource-identifiers)

Has anyone chased this down?

Comment: Are you having a particular problem?

Comment: @JoeMalin I have several specific problems.  I cannot find legal attributes and contents for the "intent" element.  I cannot find legal attributes and contents for the "Preference" element.  Etc. You are, perhaps, hinting that this question is not appropriate, as written, for SO?  Fair enough.