# Aapt add library resources

Tags: android, aapt

I'm trying to build apk manually (without gradle) according to [this manual](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676), but I don't understand how to use libraries with resources. I've downloaded Android Support Library, unzipped `appcopmpat` directory and specified `-classpath` in `javac`. I'm trying also to specify path to resources in `aapt`, but it reports name conflict. Should I just rename my app's resources, or is there a better solution?

Here's the command (`$MANIFEST` and `$ANDROID` are just paths):

```
aapt package -f -m -J app/src -M ${MANIFEST} -I ${ANDROID} -S appcompat/res app/res
```

And the error message:

```
app/res/values/strings.xml: error: Duplicate file.
appcompat/res/values/strings.xml: Original is here.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--auto-add-overlay` for duplicate resources but the problem is that, it is very difficult to figure out the proper resources commands and use. You also need to specify multiple `-S` res path for external Support Library, which are included in res inside `.aar` zip file.

Also, you can use `--extra-packages <package_name>` where you replace `<package_name>` with any package name, e.g. com.foo.bla. This will create an additional `R.java` file of the package. Instead of using a support library (e.g. AppCompatv7), you can use a theme available in `android.jar` which you would be using in main `Manifest.xml`, pointing a theme to `Styles.xml` in values folder. In this case, you would be able to use 'AAPT' tool without any support library.

Here is an article to create APK in a best way: https://geosoft.no/development/android.html.

See my answer on a similar question to use android's general theme (not available in a support library), so that you wouldn't have to integrate other libraries: [How to compile an Android app with aapt2 without using any build tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274657/how-to-compile-an-android-app-with-aapt2-without-using-any-build-tools/57210354#57210354)

Answer (score 1):

The following command can be used:

```
aapt package -f -m -J app/src -M ${MANIFEST} -I ${ANDROID} -S app/res -S appcompat/res  --extra-packages android.support.v7.app --auto-add-overlay
```

-S option before appcompat/res enable compiling code needed for app/res folder.
--auto-add-overlay enables support libraries resources to be overlayed on above of main app.
--extra-packages option for enabling R.java for appcompat too, so that appcompat will work correctly.

A working script can be found here https://github.com/HemanthJabalpuri/AndroidExplorer